# Attribute level authorization using cancancan in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancancan

I am using cancan for authorization.
I have different admin roles and I want to show them specific columns to them according to their role(admin, mega_admin). Basically I want to do something like this.

```
index do
 selectable_column
 column :first_column if can? :read_first_column #visible to mega_admin only
 column :second_column if can? :read_second_column
 actions
end
```

How do i do this since cancancan doesn't provide attribute level authorization?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the version 3.0 (https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/tree/feature/3.0.0) and the attribute level permissions feature (https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/tree/feature/3.0.0#version-30).

Note that at the present date is not released yet so you'll have to include it from github:

`gem 'cancancan', github: 'CanCanCommunity/cancancan', branch: 'feature/3.0.0'`.

When using version 3 you can define:

```
can :read, ModelClass, :first_columnn
can :read, ModelClass, :second_columnn
```

Comment: Are attribute level permissions checked by `authorize_resource`? I have been trying it to forbid `update` on a specific attribute, assigning the updated parameters in a `before_action` and seems that is not forbidding it. Seems that only works when I call `authorize! @task, :update, :priority` inside the action. What I would expect from CanCanCan is to check if the forbidden attribute was changed via dirty attributes (`priority_changed?`) and transparently authorize or not accordingly, instead of bloating my controller with lots of `authorize`. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score -2):

You would have to [define an Ability](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities) and later [check on it](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/checking-abilities):

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.mega_admin? // here 
      can :mega_manage, :all
    else if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```